# Prevent Cosmos DB Returning All Documents Until Queried In Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I've written an Azure function which halfway through the function, builds up a CosmosDb document query and excecutes it to find a document in the collection.

As I have the binding for the CosmosDB specified with no Id or Sql query supplied, does this retrieve the entire collection by default?  If so is there a way to prevent this,as I only want to query the collection once I have built the document query and return a result.

Do I need to specify a direction of inout to achieve this?

```
   public static class SynchroniseMemberData
{

    [FunctionName("SynchroniseMemberData")]
    public static void Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log,
        [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "MembersData",
                collectionName: "Members",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "offers_DOCUMENTDB"),
        ]
        DocumentClient client,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "MembersData",
            collectionName: "Members",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "offers_DOCUMENTDB")
        ]
        out object document
    )
    {

        log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());

        MemberDetails memberDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MemberDetails>(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
        Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("MembersData", "Members");
        var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionUri).Where(p => p.Id == memberDetails.id);
        var member = query.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

        if (member == null)
        {
            document = new
            {
               //Create New Member
            };
        }
        else
        {
           //update member details and save back
            document = member;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `CosmosDBTrigger` function? Post your function code if possible.

Comment: added in the code, the actual trigger is from EventGridTrigger

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing to make you think it's getting the entire collection by default?

Comment: The documentation by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#input---configuration)

Comment: Sorry I meant - what part of the code is returning the entire collection? You are using the `DocumentClient` binding for the input so not actually getting any results for anything until you do your query?

Comment: I dont beIieve that is at all, I just wanted some confirmation that DocumentClient doesn't get any result until I query it, which was what I thought was happening until I checked the documentation about binding, and if nothing is specified it brings in the whole collection

Comment: Ah I see. I don't know for definite but I'd imagine because you are using the `DocumentClient` and not specifying an input binding like `IEnumerable<MemberDetails>` that no query is performed.

Comment: To prove it - you could comment out your code and let your function run and do nothing - Go to Azure portal > your Cosmos DB collection > Metrics (under Monitoring) and see if a request was made.

Comment: Brilliant thats a great idea, that never occured to me.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pulling the `DocumentClient` does not query the collection.

In the [Bindings code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Config/CosmosDBExtensionConfigProvider.cs#L58), when you request the `DocumentClient`, it uses the `CosmosDBClientBuilder` to obtain the `DocumentClient` instance for the attribute values:

```
rule.BindToInput<DocumentClient>(new CosmosDBClientBuilder(this));
```

The `CosmosDBClientBuilder` [will obtain the `DocumentClient` instance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Bindings/CosmosDBClientBuilder.cs#L18) from the internal cache.

```
ICosmosDBService service = _configProvider.GetService(resolvedConnectionString, attribute.PreferredLocations, attribute.UseMultipleWriteLocations, attribute.UseDefaultJsonSerialization);
return service.GetClient();
```